# Spring Boot externalized configuration and system properties

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have some code that can be configured with system properties. This code is executed on start up of the application.

It seems that Spring loads properties from application.properties (or any profile dependant file) sometime later. Because of that my property defined in application.properties is not yet a system property and the code `System.getProperty` returns null.

How should I deal with such a situation? Why isn't the first thing Spring does is load all properties and then executes the rest of the code.

Comment: `This code is executed on start up of the application`. Could you provide a code snippet showing the exact point of it being executed?

Comment: It shouldn't really matter but the code lies within the init method of a servlet filter which is registered in a bean annotated method that returns a FilterRegistrationBean.

Comment: Properties in `application.properties` never become System properties. If you need them to be system properties then you'll have to copy them over yourself.